# How to adjust sensitivity(mouse dragging/rotation) speed in latest Aframe (over 1.4.2), currently using Aframe 1.5.0?

Tags: aframe

I'm working on Aframe project with latest Aframe 1.5.0 recently, I need to adjust sensitivity for flexible user experience as same as this example - https://jsfiddle.net/8gfmL1n1
But it works on very old Aframe version - I'm not sure how to implement adjusting sensitivity in latest `Aframe` for now.

Please let me know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.